# Indicator random variable review question help

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Having a bit of trouble with this review question.

A run of ones in a bitstring is a maximal consecutive of
ones. For example, the has four runs of ones: , ,
, and .
Let n ≥ 1 be an integer and consider a random bitstring of length n. Define the random
variable X to be the number of maximal runs of ones in this bitstring. 
If anyone can help me solve it, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: This won't give a general answer, but you can try simulate this about 1000 and take average maximal runs you get an estimate of expected value for a specific $n$. This can maybe give some insight or at least tell yourself if you are on the right track

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $i=1$ to $n$, let $X_i=1$ if a maximal run of $1$'s **begins** at $i$. Let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $Y$ of maximal runs of $1$'s is given by $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. By the linearity of expectation we have $E(Y)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_n)$.

Note that $\Pr(X_1=1)=\frac{1}{2}$. So $E(X_1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Note also that if $i\ge 2$ then $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{4}$. For we need a $1$ at $i$ and a $0$ at $i-1$. So for $i\ge 2$ we have $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{4}$.

It follows that our expected number is
$$\frac{1}{2}+(n-1)\frac{1}{4}.$$